# Converting utf-8 encoding in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, utf-8, export-to-csv

I am trying to use a piece of python to extract tagged words from a csv. However, I keep getting the following encoding problem. I have looked at similar issues, but my python skills are really basic. Could someone help me out, and let me know what I should change in the code?

The error I get is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

input_name =  "example.csv"      # File names for input and output
output_name = "entities.csv"


def incrementEntity(entity_string, dictionary):

    try:
        dictionary[entity_string] += 1
    except KeyError:
        dictionary[entity_string] = 1

def outputResults(dictionary, entity_type, f):

    for i in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True):
        print i, '\t', entity_type, '\t', dictionary[i]
        f.writerow([i, entity_type, dictionary[i]])

try:
    f = open(input_name, 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    f.close()
except IOError, message:
    print message
    raise ValueError("Input file could not be opened")

locations = {}  
people    = {}  
orgs      = {}

for i in soup.find_all():
    entity_name = i.get_text()
    entity_type = i.name

    if (entity_type == 'person'):
    incrementEntity(entity_name, people)
elif (entity_type == 'organization'):
    incrementEntity(entity_name, orgs)
elif (entity_type == 'location'):
   incrementEntity(entity_name, locations)
else:
    continue

output_file = open(output_name, 'w')
f = csv.writer(output_file)
print "Entity\t\tType\t\tCount"
print "------\t\t----\t\t-----"
f.writerow(["Entity", "Type", "Count"])

outputResults(people, 'person', f)
outputResults(orgs, 'organization', f)
outputResults(locations, 'location', f)
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your input file for parsing by BeautifulSoup is a csv file. I presume that's a typo.

Python's CSV library does not support Unicode so fails when trying to write non-ASCII chars.

You have three options:

1. Encode your items to UTF-8 before they're written. In `outputResults`:

   ```
   f.writerow([i.encode("utf-8"), entity_type.encode("utf-8"), dictionary[i].encode("utf-8")])
   ```
2. Create a UnicodeWriter using the broken CSV library as described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples. This will allow you to transparently write Unicode and have the encoding done for you.
3. Use a replacement for the broken CSV library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.13.0

Comment: It is a csv file that contains a row with some html tags in it. That's why I thought I would need BeautifulSoup. I'll try your first option. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, read the input it with the csv lib, then pass the html fields to BeautifulSoup